# Logical Question: How to make a LogOut on iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, view, authentication, logout

I want to have a login / logout on my iPhone App.

I have a AppDelegate which routes by  TTNavigator to my MainView.

My MainView shows a the LoginView with presentModalViewController.

Know my question is, how to do a logout?
Simply show the LoginView again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i'd do is destroy any credentials you may have stored in Memory or in a Dictionary/Keychain and also close any pending sessions. Then you can just show the LoginView again.